# Algorithm to associate components of a Voronoi Diagram

Tags: algorithm, geometry, voronoi

I have a program that so far takes a set of random points, the sites, and forms the appropriate Voronoi diagram around these points represented as a graph of corners and edges. It also gives me the Delaunay Triangulation as another graph which has all the sites as its nodes (though I can't tell if this is useful here).

So far every edge object has a record of which corners it is incident on and every corner object has records of which edges are incident on it and which other corners it is adjacent to. My aim is to be able to add to my `Edge` class two fields for the two neighbouring sites and to be able to extend my `Site` class by adding a two fields: one field containing the set of corners surrounding it and another for the set of edges around it.

I was thinking that it might be possible to generate all the individual polygons using a modified breadth-first search. However this would then require going through all the sites and working out which belongs to which polygon and this would be O(n^2) which isn't ideal. Is there a more efficient algorithm our there that can do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. If you have all the edges find the midpoint of the line and loop through the list of all sites. Sort the list and it gives the closest 2 sites. The 2 closest sites is what you want because an edge divide always 2 sites except the outer edges. Then keep a list of all edges and sites and repeat the process until there is no more edges. The clue is for the outer polygons you need only to add one site. Finally it gives a list of all polygons.

Comment: My solution seems to be O(n^2) but I think your solution requires more effort because a polygon has 6..7 faces. It also need to give the direction of the faces. Imo a bfs is O(n^3..6) does it work?